# удаление из базы в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3

Выдает следующую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ali/Рабочий стол/Папка/python/GUI/MyAc/project/accaunt.py", line 207, in <module>
    appl = Main(root, db)
  File "/home/ali/Рабочий стол/Папка/python/GUI/MyAc/project/accaunt.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.init_main()
  File "/home/ali/Рабочий стол/Папка/python/GUI/MyAc/project/accaunt.py", line 25, in init_main
    delet_acc = Button(toolbar, text='Удалить', command= self.del_acc())
  File "/home/ali/Рабочий стол/Папка/python/GUI/MyAc/project/accaunt.py", line 57, in del_acc
    self.db.c.execute('DELETE FROM account WHERE id=?',
AttributeError: 'Main' object has no attribute 'db'
```

не очень понимаю, ведь db присутствует в main

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import sqlite3

class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, db):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()
        self.db = db
        self.view_records()
        self.del_acc()

    def init_main(self):
        toolbar = Frame(bg='#FFFFE0',bd=2)
        toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

       ....
       ....

        delet_acc = Button(toolbar, text='Удалить', command= self.del_acc())
        delet_acc.pack(side=RIGHT)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=('id', 'name', 'password', 'email',
                                'app'), height=15, show='headings')
        self.tree.column('id',width=30, anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column('name',width=130, anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column('password',width=160, anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column('email',width=160, anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column('app',width=170, anchor=CENTER)

        self.tree.heading('id',text='№')
        self.tree.heading('name',text='Имя')
        self.tree.heading('password',text='Пароль')
        self.tree.heading('email',text='Почта')
        self.tree.heading('app',text='Приложение')

        self.tree.pack(side=LEFT)

    ....
    ....

    def del_acc(self):
        self.db.c.execute('DELETE FROM account WHERE id=?',
                         (self.tree.set(self.tree.selection()[0], '#1'))
                            )
        self.db.conn.commit()
        self.view_records()

    def view_records(self):
        self.db.c.execute('SELECT * FROM account')
        [self.tree.delete(i) for i in self.tree.get_children()]
        [self.tree.insert('', 'end', values = row) for row in self.db.c.fetchall()]


...
...

class DB():
    ....
...
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    db = DB()
    appl = Main(root, db)
    root.geometry("650x400")
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    __version__="0.0.1 Beta"
    root.title("MyAcc " + __version__)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delet_acc = Button(toolbar, text='Удалить', command=self.del_acc)
```

Comment: File "/home/ali/Рабочий стол/Папка/python/GUI/MyAc/project/accaunt.py", line 58, in del_acc
    (self.tree.selection()[0]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
теперь ему не нравится функция

Comment: @alexjust2200 теперь ему не нравится попытка обращения к пустому кортежу. Но это уже другой вопрос, никак не связанный с этим.